# How do I wrap objc_msgSend to take variadic arguments in the form of a va_list?

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

Instead of:

```
id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL _cmd, args...)
```

I'd like:

```
id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL _cmd, va_list args)
```

Now I realize that `objc_msgSend` **isn't** implemented in the second way for reasons Mike Ash discusses [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6983824#6984964).

But I'm developing a runtime interpreter with ObjC bridging, and I'd like one anyway, regardless of the considerable performance impact.

Now, any sane person would say:

> Why not just use [`libffi`](https://github.com/libffi/libffi)?

That's because `libffi` is outdated and broken on macOS and iOS; has been for quite some time (as of writing this post).

Is there some pre-existent wrapper for `objc_msgSend` that takes a `va_list`? I can't seem to find one, and unfortunately, at this time, lack the necessarily assembly skills to develop my own.

Comment: What are you looking to do here with this — what makes you require a `va_list`? Will the `va_list` have a known marker at the end of the list so you know when to stop iterating it? Or are you willing to do additional manual selector lookup to look for the number and types of arguments? (Because the only thing I can think of is dropping to assembly to manually deconstruct the `va_list` into arguments to pass to the first version.)

Comment: Also, if you don't care about the performance impact, why not use `NSInvocation`?

Comment: @ItaiFerber: `NSInvocation` is unavailable in Swift, whereas `va_list` is imported as `[CVarArg]` and is usable.

Comment: @ItaiFerber: I _do_ know how long the `va_list` will be.

Comment: Ah, this is coming from Swift, then? Important to note. What would you expect a callsite in Swift to look like, then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132823/discussion-between-vatsal-manot-and-itai-ferber).

Comment: @VatsalManot: `NSInvocation` is unavailable in Swift, but you can write your wrapper function whatever in Objective-C, and use that from Swift. I don't think `NSInvocation` officially supports varargs methods either, but it might not be hard to make it work.

Comment: @newacct: If you think `NSInvocation` can be made to support `va_list`, I'd be glad to accept a PoC as an answer.